# Magento 2 - ' I can't upload images on my store' gives error "wysiwyg is not under storage root path"

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg

I need to know what may be causing the issue (`wysiwyg` is not under storage root path) of not being able to upload image. Any idea would help a lot.

Here is a screenshot of the error message with red highlight

[image: Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/rohivic/pub/media/wysiwyg is not under storage root path.]

Comment: try to upload  image in other browser

Answer (score 3):

As of 2.2.3, it's not possible to upload images via the WYSIWYG if the media directory is a symlink. This is due to this [new file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Filesystem/DirectoryResolver.php#L42). UPDATE: This issue has been fixed in Magento 2.2.5 and 2.3.0. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13929) and [the fix](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.5/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Filesystem/DirectoryResolver.php#L38..L58).

### Workaround

We've temporarily fixed this by changing [this line](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Filesystem/DirectoryResolver.php#L42) from this:

```
$realPath = realpath($path);
$root = $this->directoryList->getPath($directoryConfig);
```

to this (note the addition of the `realpath` function call):

```
$realPath = realpath($path);
// BEGIN EDIT
/**
 * Since media directory is a symlink, need to run both paths through realpath in order for the comparison to
 * work.
 * The proper fix for this should involve a STORE > Configuration setting where an admin can choose whether to
 * allow symlinked directories.
 */
$root = realpath($this->directoryList->getPath($directoryConfig));
// END EDIT
```

All information taken from [this ticket](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13929) as pointiA mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Run the below command and check it:

```
php bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 0

php bin/magento c:f
```

If your folder is not showing then create the below code.

For security purposes, Magento provides Media Gallery access to contents in specific folders. The configuration path `system/media_storage_configuration/media_storage/allowed_resource/media_gallery_image_folders` in `config.xml` is used to define “Media Gallery Allowed” folders

By default, Magento allows Media Gallery access to the following two directories under /pub/media:

- `catalog/category`
- `wysiwyg`

`app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <system>
            <media_storage_configuration>
                <allowed_resources>
                    <catalog_images_folder>catalog</catalog_images_folder> <!-- Show Catalog Folder -->
                    <media_gallery_image_folders>
                        <category_image_folder>catalog/category</category_image_folder> <!--  Show Sub Catalog Folder -->
                        <my_image_folder>custom_folder_name</my_image_folder>
                        <my_catalog_image_folder>catalog/custom_folder_name</my_catalog_image_folder>
                    </media_gallery_image_folders>
                </allowed_resources>
            </media_storage_configuration>
        </system>
    </default>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like you are using the latest Magento 2.2.3. They did some security improvements that prevent using symlinks and so.

Maybe this issue will help you:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13929

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with permissions.

**For Linux** - You must run this commands:

**`find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {};`**

**For Window** - You must create a folder `wysiwyg` in this path `C:/xamp/htdocs/rohivic/pub/media/` and you *click right* on project folder to **Properties** and you must be unchecked the **Read Only**.

Comment: I am on local host using xampp. Not a live server. How do i go about that?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you St3phan for your effort. But somehow the problem seem persistent. Any more suggestions?

Comment: I updated again my answer. I added to create the folder `wysiwyg`

Answer (score -5):

Daniel
First, you can open a terminal then you can go in your Magento files then you can give permission Pub folder.

chmod -R 777 pub/

if can't working this commnad you can try to
sudo chmod -R 777 pub/

Comment: This is bad advice. Giving all directories under pub 777 permissions is dangerous for more reasons that can be covered in a Stack comment.

Comment: @JohnHall Hope you are well,
It's not bad if the folder wants permission that time we used chmod -R 700 or any other.

Comment: And Thank you give your suggestion, If the Magento instance have a permission issue in this case First he wants to check the permission of var, generated, pub/static pub/etc.
After as needed give permission.